# Perl documentation (POD) browsers?

Tags: perl, user-interface, documentation, cpan, perl-pod

I'm looking for is a good on-screen POD reading experience.

For years, I've used `perldoc` or `man` running in an `xterm` to read Perl documentation on screen, and a small custom program built around `Pod::LaTeX` to print it. The printed version is good: the script does a nice job. However, on-screen reading is painful:

- You can search, but good luck finding e.g., the `as` section in `DBIx::Class::ResultSet`. Less doesn't know anything about the structure of the document, and searches for common English words are pointless.
- I fear every time the document tells me *`see section so-and-so`*. Great. Now I have to find that. And then getting back to where I was won't be trivial (though that may be my less ignorance showing)
- See document so-and-so is worse. `!perldoc foo` works, but switching between the two documents is then hard. You can mostly get around this by suspending less and running `perldoc` from the shell, but that's more keystrokes and I'm lazy.
- Formatting leaves a lot to be desired.

I want to be able to click a table of contents, and go to that section. I want to be able to click that "see other" and go there. And so on. So far, I know of two possibilities:

- [search.cpan.org](http://search.cpan.org/), example [`DBIx::Class::ResultSet`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBIx-Class/lib/DBIx/Class/ResultSet.pm). Requires an Internet connection, but that's not normally a problem.
- [`Podbrowser`](https://github.com/gbxyz/podbrowser). Just started trying this, looks pretty nice.

I'm running Debian GNU/Linux, both Lenny and Squeeze. But please suggest programs for all platforms to make this as useful as possible.

Comment: A lot of the stuff you complain about is the stuff I just do in a separate terminal window (or screen, or whatever). I don't care so much about formatting, either. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try [Pod::Browser](https://metacpan.org/pod/Pod::Browser) which is built-in http server that you can connect to with your browser, or something like [Tk::Pod](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Tk::Pod) which is gui pod browser.

Comment: So you know, your first link is dead.

Comment: @Cptn_Hammer fixed it for mpeters

Answer (score 5):

Have you seen [CPAN::Mini::Webserver](http://search.cpan.org/dist/CPAN-Mini-Webserver) or [Pod::POM::Web](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Pod-POM-Web) or [Apache::Perldoc](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Apache-Perldoc)? These set up a local way for you to see nice, HTML versions of your docs.

Answer (score 2):

I would recomment converting all your POD to HTML using [pod2html](http://perldoc.perl.org/pod2html.html)

This makes it browsable, linked and nice looking, and you can customize look&feel via css.

Comment: This is what I use, as it's handy when disconnected from the 'net and is just as usable from the command-line with lynx (bit sadly is not in the standard MacOSX distribution, but macports has it).  I wonder if it's possible to set an ExtUtils::MakeMaker preference to build html docs by default for all installations...?

Answer (score 1):

Just to add two more POD servers that seemed to have been missed thus far!

- [Pod::Server](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Pod-Server/)
- [Pod::Webserver](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Pod-Webserver/)

Comment: What is there  to choose between these various options

Comment: @justintime : Not used Pod::Webserver so can't comment on that. But I do use Pod::Server and been very happy with it.  I like the way it renders the POD and because its built on Squatting framework I feel comfortable knowing I can make local amendments if need be (which I haven't thus far... but adding a search option would be a good idea!).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look also at Gtk2::Ex::PodViewer that is an excellent GUI viewer based on GTK. If you are using also Windows you can find a prebuilt wrapper in Camelbox (http://code.google.com/p/camelbox/).

Comment: At a first glance, podviewer (v0.18, which CPAN says is the latest) looks like a less-polished podbrowser.